# Delphi - Get folder icon

Tags: delphi, winapi

How i can get the icon of special folder for example **`Desktop`**

```
function GetFolderIcon( FName: string ): integer;
var
  FInfo: TSHFileInfo;
begin
  if SHGetFileInfo(pChar(FName), FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, FInfo, SizeOf(FInfo),
     SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX or SHGFI_SMALLICON or SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES or SHGFI_PIDL or SHGFI_ICON or SHGFI_OPENICON ) <> 0 then begin
        Result := FInfo.iIcon
    end
  else
    Result := -1;
end;
```

*GetFolderIcon(GetSpecialFolder(CSIDL_DESKTOP));* retern -1

Comment: Have you seen this? http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Pascal/Delphi/Q_20719182.html

Comment: What if -1 is a valid icon handle? It isn't, but 0 is the correct sentinel here.

Comment: Oh so you're also working with Ini Files? Is this part of this custom control? What's the value of `iniFile`?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: `SHFILEINFO.iIcon` is an index into the system image list. 0 is a valid index, but -1 is not.  So -1 is the correct return value for this code.

Comment: OK, my mistake, sorry, thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`CSIDL_DESKTOP` is the "*virtual folder that represents the Windows desktop, the root of the namespace*".  As such, it does not have a filesystem path that you can pass to `SHGetFileInfo()`.  You are probably thinking of `CSIDL_DESKTOPDIRECTORY` instead, which is "*The file system directory used to physically store file objects on the desktop (not to be confused with the desktop folder itself)*":

```
GetFolderIcon(GetSpecialFolder(CSIDL_DESKTOPDIRECTORY));
```

When calling `SHGetFileInfo()`, you can specify the `SHGFI_PIDL` flag so you can pass a `PIDL` instead of a filesystem path.  That allows for querying virtual items.  Your code is already using `SHGFI_PIDL`, but it is not using any `PIDL`s, which means you are using `SHGetFileInfo()` incorrectly to begin with.

Try this:

```
uses
  ..., ShlObj, SHFolder;

function GetSpecialFolderPath(FolderID: Integer): String;
var
  Path: array[0..MAX_PATH] of Char;
begin
  if SHGetFolderPath(0, FolderID, nil, SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, Path) = 0 then
    Result := Path
  else
    Result := '';
end;

function GetSpecialFolderPidl(FolderID: Integer): PItemIDList;
begin
  Result := nil;
  SHGetSpecialFolderLocation(0, FolderID, Result);
end;

function GetFolderIcon( FName: String ): integer; overload;
var
  FInfo: TSHFileInfo;
begin
  ZeroMemory(@FInfo, SizeOf(FInfo));
  if SHGetFileInfo(PChar(FName), FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, FInfo, SizeOf(FInfo), SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES or SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX or SHGFI_SMALLICON or SHGFI_ICON or SHGFI_OPENICON ) <> 0 then
  begin
    Result := FInfo.iIcon;
    if FInfo.hIcon <> 0 then DestroyIcon(FInfo.hIcon);
  end else
    Result := -1;
end;

function GetFolderIcon( Pidl: PItemIDList ): integer; overload;
var
  FInfo: TSHFileInfo;
begin
    if SHGetFileInfo(PChar(Pidl), FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, FInfo, SizeOf(FInfo), SHGFI_PIDL or SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES or SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX or SHGFI_SMALLICON or SHGFI_ICON or SHGFI_OPENICON ) <> 0 then
  begin
    Result := FInfo.iIcon;
    if FInfo.hIcon <> 0 then DestroyIcon(FInfo.hIcon);
  end
  else
    Result := -1;
end;
```

```
var
  Icon: Integer;
  Pidl: PItemIDList;
begin
  Icon := -1;
  Pidl := GetSpecialFolderPidl(CSIDL_DESKTOP);
  if Pidl <> nil then
  try
    Icon := GetFolderIcon(Pidl);
  finally
    CoTaskMemFree(Pidl);
  end;
end;
```

```
var
  Icon: Integer;
  Path: string;
begin
  Icon := -1;
  Path := GetSpecialFolderPath(CSIDL_DESKTOPDIRECTORY);
  if Path <> '' then
    Icon := GetFolderIcon(Path);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer.